# Get IPv6 gateway address on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, ipv6, gateway

Windows XP supports IPv6, but if I want to get the IPv6 gateway address linked to an adapter I've a big problem:

- GetAdaptersInfo can get the gateway address but works only with IPv4
- GetAdaptersAddresses works with IPv6 and can get the gateway address, but the related parameter FirstGatewayAddress of its structure ip_adapter-addresses was added only on Windows Vista and later
- Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI class can retrieve IPV6 gateway address but it is available only from Vista

EDIT:
I forgot to write I would like to get it through win32 API, not through an external library

Comment: As far as I know you can only get this information on Vista or later. And XP is long dead anyway; nobody should be writing new code for it.

Comment: Market share of Windows XP at December 2014 was about 20% [link](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems), if I could make my app retro-compatible, why not?

Comment: Why not? It encourages people to keep using an ancient, insecure operating system and putting themselves and the rest of the Internet at risk. "Drive it until it dies" might work for your old car, but it is not a good policy for computer software and operating systems.